# Suppose $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if $A$ is both open and closed, then A=Rn.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that we want to prove if $A$ does not equal the empty set then $A= \mathbb{R}^n$.
By assuming $A$ can't be the empty set we choose an $a$ in $A$ such that 
$B(a,r) \subseteq A$ . But $A$ is closed. 
I also know that in order to prove it we must show that $A$ is not bounded above, and the best way to prove that is to assume it is bounded above. So a proof by contradiction. 
I don't know what to do after we prove that it is bounded above and so $s=\sup X$ exists. 
Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What does "bounded above" mean in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: it means it has a supremum, say s=supX exists

Comment: What is the supremum of a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: There's no obvious notion of "bounded above" or "sup" in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  However, @BolzWeir's argument is good if you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and that products preserve connectedness.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\mathbb R$ is connected.

$\mathbb R^n = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \ldots \times \mathbb R$ is the Cartesian product of finitely many connected sets, hence it is itself connected.

If $A \neq \mathbb R^n$ is a non-empty clopen subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathbb R^n$ is disconnected because $(A, A^C)$ is a disconnection thus. This contradicts the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is connected.